# Arduino sound sensor only shows values between 25 - 29

Tags: audio, arduino, sensors

Arduino sound sensor does not give accurate values

I've tried reading pin from `D0` as well as reading from analog on `A0`. Pin constantly gives me `1` and `A0` gives me almost exclusively the value 26 and can go up to 29 if I blow on the sensor really hard.

```
void setup() {
    pinMode(A0, INPUT); // changes nothing
}
void loop() {
    int soundVal;
    soundVal = analogRead(A0);
    Serial.print("Sound = ");
    Serial.println(soundVal, DEC);
    delay(500);
}
```

I expect to get a value between 0 and 1024 or something like that but I only get values between 25 and 29, making it extremely difficult reading if a sound is high or low as well as if a sound was detected

Edit: I've connected GRD on the sound sensor to GRD on my Arduino, `A0` from the sound sensor to `A0` on Arduino, the + pin on the sound sensor to 5V and left the `D0` pin on the sound sensor untouched since I don't really need it I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with

> I've tried reading pin from D0 as well as reading from analog on A0

Depending on the sensor and the thing you want to achieve you can you one over the other but it's important to know the basic difference. Digital pins have only 2 states (HIGH & LOW) which you can see as 1 and 0. Read more about the digital pins [here](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/DigitalPins)

While an analog pin's value can indeed be between 0-1023. Read more about the analog pins [here](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/AnalogInputPins)

Now when we clear this. Let's move to:

> Pin constantly gives me 1 and A0 gives me almost exclusively the value
>   26 and can go up to 29 if I blow on the sensor really hard.

So clearly there is some voltage coming into your pins. I think one of two things are happening here.

1. This transition from 26-29 is nothing but a standard value changing because of the precision of the board and some other environment factors. (Which may also be broken sensor or being connected wrong)
2. I assume that you are using some sort of resistor in your circuit to make sure your sensor can handle the current. If that's the case I think you may be using a resistor with a much higher resistance than what is needed for the sensor.

When it comes to the code it's straightforward, you are doing it right. Attach a scheme or provide information about your circuit if you want more detailed help.

Comment: I managed to get as high as 189 at one point. Changing the resistor strength does change the value but getting the sensor to actually react is difficult. Depending on the resistor I get everything from 26, 1 and 11 as a standard value when no sound is present. Making noises, such as blowing in the mic or talking does almost nothing to change the value no matter what the resistor strength is...

Comment: @py_enc can you drop the sensor's name here, It's possible to be just hardware limitation.

Comment: The company that sold me the sound sensor only describes it as "sound sensor". However, a quick google search for Arduino Sound Sensor reveals it. It's the red one, NOT "high quality 1Pc", with four pins, a blue box thingy on the board and a fairly large metal cylinder with a black top where the sound goes in. I believe it's the LM393

Comment: @py_enc great here there is very useful information https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=257894.0 one of the comments even describes your problem 1:1 xaxa (from the user called jay11421)

Comment: So basically it only works on close range? Like really close range? It's not that I have configured it wrong nor that the values are incorrect but rather that it sucks? haha

Comment: @py_enc I've never used it before but it may most likely be the case haha

Answer (score 0):

It appears as if the sound sensor does work but really only cares about sound changes REALLY close to it, hence why the numbers does not really change. Solution: buy another sound sensor or adapt accordingly.